# Postgres out of memory error

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR:  out of memory DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 23.
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: out of memory SQL state: 53200 Detail: Failed on request of
>   size 23.

Can somebody help me understand how to resolve it?

Comment: I can't help as I've never had this issue, but maybe you should say what exactly yo're doing to get the error.

Comment: First you'll have to figure out if the errors comes from the server or the client. If from the server, share the memory dump from the log. Make sure to add the offending query to the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Increased RAM of the host. Seemed to solve the issue. This error did not occur again.